# css image on the left, title and text on the rights

Tags: html, css

i am trying to put a image in a div on the left side. On the right side of it, i need to put a title and (under the title) the text

i want to have the title and the text always on the right of the image

I can not have it, the text goes back under the image

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=60Npd0DQ8G

Thanks in advance

Comment: there's empty fiddle, place your code in the question...

Comment: fiddle seems to work for me..

Comment: But can you be clear which image, and what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: its something team fiddle (collaboration), it behaves annoyingly!

Comment: Post your relevant code in the question.

Comment: Every thing seems to e working fine what is your actual problem

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

Create two DIVs. Float them left. Place the image in Div #A and nest more DIVs for Title and Text in DIV #B. Surround the whole thing in another DIV with Overflow Hidden (or apply some kind of "clearfix hack" to whatever element follows Div #B).

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
   <div id="A" style="float:left; width: 50%;">
      <img src="yourimage.jpg">
   </div>
   <div id="B" style="float: left; width: 50%;">
      <div>
         Title
      </div>
      <div>
         Text
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it as:

```
<p>
    This is some text.
    <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" align="middle"> This is some text.</img>
</p>
```

The text after the image align on the right middle of that.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/tvznazum/)**

css

```
img, .wrapper_rand {
    display: inline-block; /* make them in one line */
     word-wrap: break-word; /* break very long words */
    border: 1px solid black; /* just for display */
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical centering */

}
.wrapper_rand {
    width: calc(100% - 300px); /* this will make sure that right div will occupy remaining space (1005 - width of image) */
}
img {
    width:256px; /* width of image */
}
ul {
    list-style: none; /* no styles of li */
}
```